# How to find the position of every word in a sentence(string) where the same word is used many times in a sentence using functions in python

Tags: python, function

how to find the position of every word in a sentence(string) where the same word is used more than 1 time using functions and input in python?

I am finding the position of one the word in the string but the position of the second is not appearing

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the code you've written so far, even if it is not yet working properly.

Comment: Please also see [ask]. Your actual code is much better than a description of your code to show us what you've done. Please take the [tour] and read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!